# Why the origin is globally asymptotically stable?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

If the Lyapunov function is 
$$
V(x) = x^2_1 + x^2_2-1 
$$
And its time derivative is 
$$
\dot{V}(x) = -(x^2_1 + x^2_2)
$$
Why the origin is globally asymptotically stable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, $V(x) = x^2_1 + x^2_2-1 $ is not a Lyapunov function because it is not positive definite. But one can take $W(x)=V(x)+1=x^2_1 + x^2_2$. It is positive definite, radially unbounded and its derivative
$\dot W(x)=\dot V(x)+0=-(x^2_1 + x^2_2)$ is negative definite; thus, the origin is [globally asymptotically stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function#Globally_asymptotically_stable_equilibrium).

Comment: The answer I have states because $\dot{V}<0, x\neq 0$ and $V$ has a single minimum which is globally asymptotically stable. I didn't understand this justification.

Comment: This is a slightly abbreviated rephrased proof of the stability theorem. In the proof of the Lyapunov stability theorem, the value of $V$ at the origin is chosen zero for convenience. It can be anything, as I showed in my answer.